# c:4:25: error: expected identifier or '(' before '{' token

Tags: c, struct, types, macros, syntax-error

I tried to implement template like functionality in C by use of macros, but for some reason it throws me the error "c:4:25: error: expected identifier or '(' before '{' token"

Here's the code

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#define test(name, type){\
    typedef struct{\
        type x;\
        type y;\
    }name;\
}
test(IntVec2, int);
int main(){
    printf("Hello, World!");
}
```

Comment: `{typedef...}` is not a valid declaration

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I have now realized that remove the brackets solves the problem

Comment: All compilers have a way to stop after preprocessing, to let you show how macros were expanded. I suggest you do that and look at it, to see what your macro created.

Comment: I've worked with macros and am aware of how they function and work. It was just a silly mistake on my part. Probably need to catch up on some more sleep!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to debug this type of situation is to take a look at the output of the preprocessor. For exampl, we feed the following through the `cpp` preprocessor:

```
#define test(name, type){\
    typedef struct{\
        type x;\
        type y;\
    }name;\
}
test(IntVec2, int);
```

(I have omitted some of the code)

The result of the `cpp` program, is something like:

```
# 0 "test.c"
# 0 "<built-in>"
# 0 "<command-line>"
# 1 "/usr/include/stdc-predef.h" 1 3 4
# 0 "<command-line>" 2
# 1 "test.c"

{ typedef struct{ int x; int y; }IntVec2;};
```

Now it becomes immediately apparent that the first `{` and last `}` should not have been in the macro definition.

Thus:

```
#define test(name, type)\
    typedef struct{\
        type x;\
        type y;\
    }name;
test(IntVec2, int);
```

Now leads to:

```
# 0 "test.c"
# 0 "<built-in>"
# 0 "<command-line>"
# 1 "/usr/include/stdc-predef.h" 1 3 4
# 0 "<command-line>" 2
# 1 "test.c"

typedef struct{ int x; int y; }IntVec2;;
```

Note that even now, the `;` at the end is obsolete (but relatively harmless in this specific case. Be very careful when using `;` within macro definitions.

Answer (score 0):

Removing the brackets solves the problem as {typedef...} is not a valid declaration as stated by Mat in the comments.